# HTML data is not rendering properly in UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am really confuse. Probably HTML data is not correct format so it is not rendering in UIWebView. Below is code :

```
 self.contentBlog.frame.size.height = 1
    self.contentBlog.frame.size = self.contentBlog.sizeThatFits(.zero)
 self.contentBlog.delegate = self;
self.contentBlog.loadHTMLString(dataString, baseURL: nil)
```

below is html data link which i am getting using web services.I was not able to paste content because it was not accepting.

> http://collabedit.com/57h26